# band pass filter for removing noise in the set sound (collection of sound ) in python

Tags: python, audio

how will we use a bandpass filter for removing noise in the set sound (collection of sound ) not only one sound but a set of sounds?? using a python programming language

I have a set of audio waves (example: lung sound signal). each sound has one .text extension. so, I want to remove noise from all audio and then I will connect audio with .text. and finally I will finish my work.
the main point I need is to remove noise through preprocessing step in deep learning. how will I do it?

please, help

Comment: This really is a question of the "please do my work" type. You need to do some work and get help with problems (one by one) as they arise.

Answer (score 1):

There's a recipe on Scipy cookbook for a butterworth bandpass:
https://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ButterworthBandpass.html

You might be able to adapt that as your bandpass, but it sort of depends a bit on the frequencies you want to be able to filter out.

I'd say it would be easier to do your audio pre-processing in an audio specific programme, there are free ones out there like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) and then feed the processed data into your deep learning module. Good luck!